# Facebook comment cut off locally?

Tags: facebook, comments, local, cut

My facebook comment box is getting off vertically when I run my site locally with rails, but when I upload it to heroku and view it there it seems to autosize fine.  Any idea why this might be?  Is it because my localhost is unreachable from facebooks servers? Is there a way to get it to show properly locally?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the parent element has:

```
overflow: visible;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Pluggin, you have to quit all the codes like

```
. facebook-comment { width: 95px !important; }
```

These codes are setting-up automatically by the plugin and don't work with all css functionalities.

Once you have done that, you can create a `<div class>` in your PHP console and adding it in your CSS file to customize your box as you want.